# if and $_SESSION with $POST

Tags: php, parameters

I'm sure this is a rookie question but I get undefined index in the `$_POST` password parameter.

```
if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
   echo 'Hi 2 '.$_SESSION['Password'].'<br>';
}
```

If I do the following with either with `$_SESSION` or `$_POST`, I get the correct echo line.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['Password'])){                     
    echo 'Hi 2 '.$_SESSION['Password'].'<br>';               
}
```

Can it be that same parameters cannot be used for both variables ?

Comment: Check your input name property is set to `Password` in the HTML code.

Comment: First you should understand what is SESSION and POST variables.  SESSION is used to store a session variable that can be accessed throughout the session from any php document. POST is used to get any variable that send through the post method. 

In the first code snippet you are checking weather the SESSION['password'] == POST['password'] and you are not providing any value through post method thats why you are getting an undefined error. So to over come this one the best way is to check weather is both of the variable has defined by using isset function.

Comment: how can your `POST` data ! Show your form html .Also session will store after password is sent ,so should check password from database !!

Comment: Hmm not sure how to post code here. In order to check that my code was correct, I replaced the line if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']) with if (!empty($_POST['Password'])) and then if (!empty($_SESSION['Password'])) and both echoed the correct values. Once they are combined and compared, it crashes.

Comment: Why are you storing the password in the session?

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand what is SESSION and POST variables.
**SESSION** is used to store a session variable that can be accessed throughout the session from any PHP document.
  **POST**  is used to get any variable that send through the post method.

> In the first code snippet you are checking weather the 
>   **SESSION['Password'] == POST['Password']**
>   and you are not providing any value through post method and the post variable 'Password' is not defined in your program to that's why you are getting an undefined error.

So to over come this one the best way is to check weather both of the variable has defined or not by using isset function.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Password']) && isset($_POST['Password'])){
    if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){
        echo 'Hi 2 '.$_SESSION['Password'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

> Provide the value for POST['Password'] through a correct statement then the code will work. 
>   I think you know how to set values for SESSION variable because you are comparing a SESSION variable with a POST variable.

Comment: yes. but you have to pass value for post variable and set value for session variable

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['Password']) && isset($_POST['Password'])){   //Works  and does the echo within the if statement.       
if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password']){  // Does not and gives Undefined index.

Comment: Can I post the whole code. It's not long, just a test program.

Comment: @marsheng yes sure you can

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['Password'], $_POST['Password']) && $_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password'])` would be easier to read, you also have an extra `]` on the password.

Comment: I think I have found my mistake. Each time the form was opening, I was resetting $_SESSION['Password'] so it didn't like the statement " if ($_SESSION['Password'] == $_POST['Password'])" as it was comparing a null to a string. Would this give an "undefined index" error ?

Comment: @marsheng please provide the full code then it will be easy for us to debug.